# Can't access methods in super class

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I define a parent class and a child class as follows:

```
class A(object):
    def a_method(self):
        print "A!"

class B(A):
    def b_method(self):
        super(A, self).a_method()
        print "B!"

b_obj = B()
```

I would expect the following to print out "A!" and "B!", however it throws an error:

```
b_obj = B()

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'a_method'
```

I'm baffled. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you wanted :

```
super(B, self).a_method()
```

Otherwise you'll skip past A in the [mro](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

Everything else looks OK.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, since you also referenced the mro, which answered a related question I had. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the current class to super, not the superclass:

```
class B(A):
    def b_method(self):
        super(B, self).a_method()
    #         ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do `super(B, self)` instead of `super(A, self)`. You need to access B's superclass, not A's.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the current class to `super`. From [the official `super` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

> super(type[, object-or-type])
>
> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type.

This is the correct code:

```
super(B, self).a_method()
```